# Different error message if I include an exception in Request rules

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, dingo-api

I have the following update function for my model:

```
public function update(PartnerRequest $request, $id)
{
    $partner = Partner::findOrFail($id);

    if(!$partner -> update($request->all())) {
        throw new HttpException(500);
    }

    return response()->json([
            'status' => 'ok'
        ], 201);

}
```

And here is the request file:

```
namespace App\Api\V1\Requests;

use Config;
use Dingo\Api\Http\FormRequest;

class PartnerRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
               'name' => 'required|unique:partners,' . $this->id . ',id',
               'email' => 'email'    
        ];
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If I remove the exception on the rule and make it as `'name' => 'required|unique:partners'`, I have the following error message in case of duplicate inputs:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
    "errors": {
      "name": [
        "The name has already been taken."
      ]
    },
    "status_code": 422
  }
}
```

But the problem is on Patch, where I cannot update the model (due to the unique name rule). So, I need the exception. However, if I include it, instead of the above specific error, I have a generic one like this:

```
  "error": {
    "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: partners.name (SQL: update \"partners\" set \"name\" = test, \"updated_at\" = 2017-03-03 10:47:53 where \"id\" = 3)",
    "code": "23000",
    "status_code": 500
  }
}
```

Routes:

```
$api->post('partner/store', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\PartnerController@store');
$api->get('partner/all', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\PartnerController@index');
$api->get('partner/{id}', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\PartnerController@show');
$api->patch('partner/{id}', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\PartnerController@update');
```

Comment: What's your main reason for putting your validation rules in `Config`?

Comment: Using a starter for Laravel API and it is like it is used. https://github.com/francescomalatesta/laravel-api-boilerplate-jwt However, I tried it also to copy paste the rules in the file and I still have the same behaviour.

Comment: Can you show the `Route` for this?

Comment: @RossWilson Updated with routes and rules directly on the formrequest instead of config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing something like:

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'POST':
            return [
                'name' => 'required|unique:partners',
                'email' => 'email'
            ];
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':

        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:partners,name,' . $this->route('id') . ',id',
            'email' => 'email'
        ];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In this case, I have the right message error in the store method, but if the update has another already used name, it has the generic error :(

Comment: @Tasos I updated my answer. You had an issue in your original logic as you weren't passing the column name before the ignore logic.

Comment: It works now but I had to change the `route('id). ',id'` to `route('name').',name'`

Comment: @Tasos Fair enough. I'd assumed `id` because the Route you posted above said `'partner/{id}'`.